# git-tfs Access to path <sha> is denied

Tags: tfs, git-tfs

I am trying to clone a TFS project using git-tfs and I didn't get very far.  See below

```
$ git tfs quick-clone [my-server] $/path/to/my/branch
Initialized empty Git repository in c:/source/git/MyProject/.git/
101 objects created...
265 objects created...
433 objects created...
Access to the path '3eacdc95b116e38cf26ebab188525feb98bc84' is denied.
```

I can checkout this project in Visual Studio 2010, but it isn't without problems either.  There are a few large (2-5MB) PDF files in the source that cause Team Explorer to timeout when doing a checkout over VPN.  I can simply cloak these large files so that they are excluded and then visual studio has no problems at all.

Any ideas?  Is this a configuration problem on the TFS server?  Could it be caused by the large binary files?

Any tip is appreciated, I'd really hate to lose git while on this TFS-managed project...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the same as an issue raised on the githib site. https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/issues/107

From the thread it looks like a problem with TFS that was fixed in SP1.  Check you have the latest service packs installed on the TFS server and also your VS install.

Comment: I haven't been able to confirm this since I don't own the TFS server.    But it's what I was looking for.